# 'WRITE not allowed' error received when file is open

Tags: cobol

When running the code below, which outputs a report of all those who get bonuses based on input files, I get the error, 'WRITE not allowed, file not open for output (status = 48)' on ln 159.

I have tried opening the file in the 500-HEADING module but receive an error saying 'file already open (status = 41)' and receive the original error with moving the OPEN statement around to the 100-MAIN module. Using I-O, INPUT-OUTPUT, and EXTEND return a syntax error.

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. ASSIGNMENT9_1_SORT.
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT PAYROLL-MASTER ASSIGN TO 'CH0901-UNSORTED.DAT'
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
           SELECT WORK-FILE ASSIGN TO 'TEMP.DAT'
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
           SELECT BONUS-REPORT ASSIGN TO 'BONUS REPORT SORTED.LST'
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD  PAYROLL-MASTER.
       01  PAYROLL-REC.
           05 EMP-NO-IN                 PIC X(5).
           05 NAME-IN                   PIC X(20).
           05 TERRITORY-NO-IN           PIC XX.
           05 OFFICE-NO-IN              PIC XX.
           05 ANNUAL-SALARY-IN          PIC 9(6).
           05                           PIC X(29).
           05 DATE-HIRED-IN.
                10 MONTH-IN             PIC 99.
                10 DAY-IN               PIC 99.
                10 YEAR-IN              PIC 9999.
           05                           PIC X(10).
       FD  BONUS-REPORT.
       01  BONUS-PRINT                  PIC X(80).
       SD  WORK-FILE.
       01  SORT-REC.
           05 EMP-NO                    PIC X(5).
           05 S-NAME                    PIC X(20).
           05 TERR                      PIC XX.
           05 OFFICE                    PIC XX.
           05 ANNUAL-SALARY             PIC 9(6).
           05                           PIC X(29).
           05 DATE-HIRED.
                10 S-MONTH              PIC 99.
                10 S-DAY                PIC 99.
                10 S-YEAR               PIC 9999.
           05                           PIC X(10).
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01  BONUS-REC.
           05 EMP-NO-OUT                PIC X(5).
           05 NAME-OUT                  PIC X(20).
           05 TERRITORY-NO-OUT          PIC XX.
           05 OFFICE-NO-OUT             PIC XX.
           05 ANNUAL-SALARY-OUT         PIC 9(6).
           05                           PIC X(29).
           05 DATE-HIRED-OUT.
               10 MONTH-OUT             PIC 99.
               10 DAY-OUT               PIC 99.
               10 YEAR-OUT              PIC 9999.
           05                           PIC X(10).
       01  WS-DATE.
           05 WS-YEAR                   PIC 9999.
           05 WS-MONTH                  PIC 99.
           05 WS-DAY                    PIC 99.
       01  HEADER1.
           05                           PIC X(40) VALUE SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(15) VALUE 'BONUS REPORT'.
           05                           PIC X(5) VALUE SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(5) VALUE 'PAGE '.
           05 PAGE-NO                   PIC 99 VALUE 1.
           05                           PIC XXX.
           05 TODAYS-DATE.
              10 MONTH-FIELD            PIC 99.
              10                        PIC X VALUE '/'.
              10 DAY-FIELD              PIC XX.
              10                        PIC X VALUE '/'.
              10 YEAR-FIELD             PIC 9999.
       01  BLANK-LINE                          PIC X(80).
       01  FIRST-RECORD                 PIC X VALUE 'Y'.
       01  HEADER2.
           05                           PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(13) VALUE 'TERRITORY --'.
           05 TERRITORY-NO              PIC 99.
       01  HEADER3.
           05                           PIC X(20) VALUE SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(10) VALUE 'OFFICE --'.
           05 OFFICE-NO                 PIC 99.
       01  HEADER4.
           05                           PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(15) VALUE 'EMPLOYEE NAME'.
           05                           PIC X(5) VALUE SPACES.
           05                           PIC X(5) VALUE 'BONUS'.
       01  DATA1.
           05                           PIC X(6) VALUE SPACES.
           05 NAME                      PIC X(20).
           05                           PIC XXXX.
           05 BONUS                     PIC $ZZ,ZZZ.99 VALUE ZEROES.
       01  ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS       PIC X VALUE 'Y'.
       01  LINE-COUNT                   PIC 99 VALUE 1.

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       100-MAIN.
           SORT WORK-FILE
             ON ASCENDING KEY TERR
             ON ASCENDING KEY OFFICE
             USING PAYROLL-MASTER
             GIVING BONUS-REPORT
           PERFORM 200-INPUT
           STOP RUN.

       200-INPUT.
           OPEN INPUT BONUS-REPORT
           MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE TO WS-DATE
           MOVE WS-YEAR TO YEAR-FIELD
           MOVE WS-MONTH TO MONTH-FIELD
           MOVE WS-DAY TO DAY-FIELD
           PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'N'
                READ BONUS-REPORT NEXT RECORD
                   AT END
                      MOVE 'N' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
                   NOT AT END
                      PERFORM 300-MOVE
                      PERFORM 400-CALC
                END-READ
           CLOSE BONUS-REPORT
           END-PERFORM.

       300-MOVE.
           MOVE EMP-NO-IN TO EMP-NO-OUT
           MOVE NAME-IN TO NAME-OUT
           MOVE TERRITORY-NO-IN TO TERRITORY-NO-OUT
           MOVE OFFICE-NO-IN TO OFFICE-NO-OUT
           MOVE ANNUAL-SALARY-IN TO ANNUAL-SALARY-OUT
           MOVE DATE-HIRED-IN TO DATE-HIRED-OUT.

       400-CALC.
           MOVE ZEROES TO BONUS
           IF YEAR-OUT IS LESS THAN 1994
               COMPUTE BONUS = ANNUAL-SALARY-OUT * 0.10
           END-IF
           EVALUATE TRUE
             WHEN FIRST-RECORD = 'Y'
                MOVE TERRITORY-NO-OUT TO TERRITORY-NO
                MOVE OFFICE-NO-OUT TO OFFICE-NO
                PERFORM 500-HEADING
                MOVE NAME-OUT TO NAME
                WRITE BONUS-PRINT FROM DATA1
                ADD 1 TO LINE-COUNT
                MOVE 'N' TO FIRST-RECORD
             WHEN FIRST-RECORD = 'N'
                MOVE TERRITORY-NO-OUT TO TERRITORY-NO
                MOVE OFFICE-NO-OUT TO OFFICE-NO
                MOVE NAME-OUT TO NAME
                IF LINE-COUNT > 10
                   MOVE 1 TO LINE-COUNT
                   ADD 1 TO PAGE-NO
                   PERFORM 500-HEADING
                END-IF
           WRITE BONUS-PRINT FROM DATA1
           ADD 1 TO LINE-COUNT
           END-EVALUATE.

       500-HEADING.
           WRITE BONUS-PRINT FROM BLANK-LINE
           WRITE BONUS-PRINT FROM HEADER1
           WRITE BONUS-PRINT FROM BLANK-LINE
           WRITE BONUS-PRINT FROM HEADER2
           WRITE BONUS-PRINT FROM BLANK-LINE
           WRITE BONUS-PRINT FROM HEADER3
           WRITE BONUS-PRINT FROM BLANK-LINE
           WRITE BONUS-PRINT FROM BLANK-LINE
           WRITE BONUS-PRINT FROM HEADER4.
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
       OPEN INPUT BONUS-REPORT
```

To

```
       OPEN OUTPUT BONUS-REPORT
```

---

Upon further examination addition errors were found.

The `SORT` statement should have created different file to use as input, rather than the file that you intended to use for output. Or, as @Jim Castro implies in another answer, use the `OUTPUT PROCEDURE` to access the records. The differences below show the additional file and the `OPEN` and `CLOSE` statements for that file.

Also,the `CLOSE` statement needed to removed from the `PERFORM`. also noted by @Jim Castro.

Finally, the `END-EVALUATE` need to be placed before the `WRITE` statement.

The following is the output of a difference utility that identifies the changes.
*OLD* being the program you posted, *NEW* being the program after the changes I applied.

```
* Text File Comparison
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* 000008/000008: mis-matched records
* OLD :-
           SELECT WORK-FILE ASSIGN TO 'TEMP.DAT'
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
* NEW :-
           SELECT WORK-FILE ASSIGN TO 'TEMP.DAT'.
           SELECT TEMP-BONUS-FILE ASSIGN TO "TEMP-BONUS.DAT"
           ORGANIZATION LINE SEQUENTIAL.
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* 000027/000028: extra NEW records :-
       FD  TEMP-BONUS-FILE.
       01  TEMP-BONUS-REC.
           05 T-EMP-NO                  PIC X(5).
           05 T-NAME                    PIC X(20).
           05 T-TERR                    PIC XX.
           05 T-OFFICE                  PIC XX.
           05 T-ANNUAL-SALARY           PIC 9(6).
           05                           PIC X(29).
           05 T-DATE-HIRED.
                10 T-MONTH              PIC 99.
                10 T-DAY                PIC 99.
                10 T-YEAR               PIC 9999.
           05                           PIC X(10).
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* 000102/000116: mis-matched records
* OLD :-
             GIVING BONUS-REPORT
* NEW :-
             GIVING TEMP-BONUS-FILE
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* 000107/000121: mis-matched records
* OLD :-
           OPEN INPUT BONUS-REPORT
* NEW :-
           OPEN INPUT TEMP-BONUS-FILE
               OUTPUT BONUS-REPORT
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* 000113/000128: mis-matched records
* OLD :-
                READ BONUS-REPORT NEXT RECORD
* NEW :-
                READ TEMP-BONUS-FILE NEXT RECORD
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* 000120/000135: mis-matched records
* OLD :-
           CLOSE BONUS-REPORT
           END-PERFORM.

       300-MOVE.
           MOVE EMP-NO-IN TO EMP-NO-OUT
           MOVE NAME-IN TO NAME-OUT
           MOVE TERRITORY-NO-IN TO TERRITORY-NO-OUT
           MOVE OFFICE-NO-IN TO OFFICE-NO-OUT
           MOVE ANNUAL-SALARY-IN TO ANNUAL-SALARY-OUT
           MOVE DATE-HIRED-IN TO DATE-HIRED-OUT.
* NEW :-
           END-PERFORM
           CLOSE BONUS-REPORT TEMP-BONUS-FILE.

       300-MOVE.
           MOVE T-EMP-NO TO EMP-NO-OUT
           MOVE T-NAME TO NAME-OUT
           MOVE T-TERR TO TERRITORY-NO-OUT
           MOVE T-OFFICE TO OFFICE-NO-OUT
           MOVE T-ANNUAL-SALARY TO ANNUAL-SALARY-OUT
           MOVE T-DATE-HIRED TO DATE-HIRED-OUT.
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* 000154/000169: mis-matched records
* OLD :-
           WRITE BONUS-PRINT FROM DATA1
           ADD 1 TO LINE-COUNT
           END-EVALUATE.
* NEW :-
           END-EVALUATE
           WRITE BONUS-PRINT FROM DATA1
           ADD 1 TO LINE-COUNT.
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

I should add that the `300-MOVE` paragraph could be replaced by using `INTO BONUS-REC` on either a `READ` or `RETURN` statement; as in,

```
    READ TEMP-BONUS-FILE NEXT RECORD INTO BONUS-REC
```

or

```
    RETURN SORT-REC INTO BONUS-REC
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I applied this and unfortunately was met with the same issue, although now saying the input is not open. 'READ/START not allowed, file not open for input (status = 47)'. This occurs with the read statment that is part of the 200-INPUT module on ln 113. I also tried just simply doing 

`OPEN INPUT BONUS-REPORT 
           OUTPUT BONUS-REPORT`

but get the error that the file is already open. Could the issue possibly lie within my SORT?

Answer (score 2):

Nice first attempt but you are doing many things wrong.  You cannot open BONUS-REPORT as input if its the final formatted output of your program.  Some files are I-O but this isn't the case here.

I would suggest using the SORT verb with USING with OUTPUT PROCEDURE IS version of the statement instead.  RETURN the SORT-REC then format and WRITE the bonus report. You'll have to change your 300 and 400 paragraphs to move the right fields but it should work out for you in the end.

```
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   100-MAIN.

       SORT WORK-FILE
         ON ASCENDING KEY TERR
         ON ASCENDING KEY OFFICE
         USING PAYROLL-MASTER
         OUTPUT PROCEDURE IS PERFORM 200-OUTPUT

       GOBACK.

   200-OUTPUT.
       OPEN OUTPUT BONUS-REPORT
       MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE TO WS-DATE
       MOVE WS-YEAR TO YEAR-FIELD
       MOVE WS-MONTH TO MONTH-FIELD
       MOVE WS-DAY TO DAY-FIELD

       PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'N'
             RETURN SORT-REC INTO BONUS-REC              
               AT END
                  MOVE 'N' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
               NOT AT END
                  PERFORM 400-CALC
            END-RETURN
       END-PERFORM.

       CLOSE BONUS-REPORT.
```

Please note: move the close of BONUS-REPORT out of the PERFORM loop.

Comment: With `INTO BONUS-REC`, `PERFORM 300-MOVE` should be removed. Notice that `300-MOVE` actually moves fields from `PAYROLL-REC` in the `FILE SECTION`. The fields in that record should not be used as sending fields after the sort. Removing the perform, removes the problem.

Comment: @Rick Smith  Yes,  300-MOVE isn't necessary and can (should) be removed.  Open COBOL doesn't seem to mind that the fields come from an unopened file but under Z/OS it would crash with an 0C4 memory exception so it's just good practice to remove it.